# applescript add song to iTunes playlist via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, itunes

When I have the track name in quotes it successfully adds the track to the playlist "talks". See example:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    duplicate track "Big Ruby Conf 2013 Keynote by Jim Weirich-vIHdhaF2R2w.mp3" to      playlist "talks"
end tell
```

But what I want to do is pass in a command line argument for the track that I want to add to my playlist, like so:

```
on run argv
    tell application "iTunes"
        duplicate track argv to playlist "talks"
    end tell
end run
```

When I do that I get this error:

```
osascript add_track_to_talks.scpt  "Big Ruby Conf 2013 Keynote by Jim Weirich-vIHdhaF2R2w.mp3"
    add_track_to_talks.scpt: execution error: iTunes got an error: A descriptor type    mismatch occurred. (-10001)
```

I know passing command line arguments works because I wrote something simple to test it:

```
on run arg
    log "hello: " & arg
end run
```

When I run it with this command:

```
osascript log_test.scpt "Blake"
```

I get this output:

```
hello: Blake
```

Any ideas on the correct way to pass in a track name as a command line argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference one item from argv, which is a list:

```
on run argv
    tell application "iTunes"
        duplicate track (first item of argv) to playlist "talks"
    end tell
end run
```